# Angular value service not updating view

Tags: angularjs

Im building a quiz and at the homepage I allow people to enter their name, so its shown on the screen the entire time. I thought a value service would be the best for this.

MainCtrl:

```
angular
        .module('myQuiz')
        .controller('MainController', ["CONSTANTS", 'User', MainController]);

    function MainController(CONSTANTS, User) {  

        vm = this;

        vm.title = CONSTANTS.TITLE;

        vm.user = User.name;     
    };
```

values.js

```
angular
    .module('myQuiz')
    .value("User", {
        name: "John Doe"
    });
```

And the HomeCtrl which is a child of mainctrl:

```
angular
        .module('myQuiz')
        .controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$location', 'User', HomeController]);

    function HomeController($scope, $location, User) {

        $scope.test = "Enter your name to start the quiz";

        $scope.user;

        function startQuiz (name) {
            setUserName(name);
            return $location.path('/quiz');
        }

        function setUserName(name) {
            User.name = name;
            console.log(User.name);
        }

        $scope.startQuiz = startQuiz;



    };
```

In the mainctrl it shows John Doe, but when i console log it, it shows the right input. Why isnt it updating?

Comment: show your view/html also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `vm.user = User.name;` to `vm.user = User`;

This is because you are trying to bind to a primitive data type (String). You need to bind to the object instead. Here is a pretty good explanation as to why:

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't even need to know it is happening... until you try 2-way data binding (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string, boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope. It doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the parent property of the same name. This is not something AngularJS is doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works.
>
> source: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes.

Here is another article that might be a little easier to follow: http://www.codelord.net/2014/05/10/understanding-angulars-magic-dont-bind-to-primitives/